# How to implement a user with different roles depending on facility

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

Excuse the title as this situation is difficult to explain.

Imagine a business with multiple facilities, and each user's roles are directly tied to a facility. Therefore, each user has different permissions for each facility, modeled by the use of a "role". For example, Bob is an Admin for Facility X, therefore can manage users for Facility X. However, Bob is only a EndUser for Facility Y, and can only view static information about Facility Y.

**I have two main questions:**

1. Has anyone been able to model this with Asp.Net Identity 2.0? It seems like I could just add a "FacilityId" column to the User_Role table, but I have ran into issues with this.
2. Is this only similar, or is it exactly the same idea as a "multi-tenant" application?

Comment: I think you can create a buffer table with user identity, facility identity as composite key and a role to determine which role in a particular facility a user will take

Comment: To me it sounds like Role is not made for this. I'd use Claims for this. There are many examples on how to implement claims based authorized attributes. If you build a matrix of your facility/permissions then you can see if the user can has a match